# Why is java var type variables not working?

Tags: java

I declared var type variable however the program throws compilation error. Can someone suggest the reason for this error?

```
var avg2 = 10.0;
```

Error:

```
javac "VarTypeVariables.java" (in directory: S:\29032020 Java\12 Var Type Variables)
VarTypeVariables.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        var avg2 = 10.0; //type based on 10.0 (i.e double)
        ^
  symbol:   class var
  location: class VarTypeVariables
1 error
Compilation failed.
```

Code:

```
class VarTypeVariables {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        var avg2 = 10.0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: `var` works in Java 10+

Comment: @Eran I have java :

Comment: @Eran I have :
C:\Users\Sandun_S_V>java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: @ernest_k how can i specifically find it out ?

Comment: What you show there says you're running Java 8. You need to upgrade to Java 10 or newer to be able to use `var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from the `java -version command` you posted above indicates you are using Java 8. `var` was only introduced in to the language at java 10.

If you want to use `var` you need to install a more recent version of Java - Java 10 or above.

Answer (score 0):

var keyword  was added in `java 10` for type inference. You have to upgrade to this version of `java` to make this example working.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be you are using an older version of java.
In Java 10, the `var` keyword has been introduced. e.g. instead of doing `String str = "Java"`, you can now just say `var str = "Java"`.

Answer (score 0):

I already had the Java 17 version in use and it still didn't work. So I made the settings below and it worked.

Add to pom.xml:

```
<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
<java.version>17</java.version>
```

Go to: Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b2PY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error using java 17. I change java version on spring boot project in the same moment the project was running. And after this state showed up.

To fix this, change java version again e clean your project with > mvn clean, after reload the project and its done!